# Show blank page in new private browsing window of Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-bootstrap

In Firefox 42, when a new private browsing window is opened, it shows the information about *Tracking Protection*. How to show a blank page instead? I know it can be done via `override` directive in `chrome.manifest` but I am looking for a way to do it in JavaScript in a bootstrapped add-on (without the SDK).